# AJAX log show success but no data posted to php

Tags: php, ajax

I used ajax to post html `data-attr` value but when i post i get following log in console

in console log, i get this result

```
   success
   posted_ads:201 array(0) {
                     }
```

As log states `AJAX` success, so i thought there might be error in php so used `var_dump()` method to find there are any data passed form request but no dump data.

Any solution why i don't get any data on `php`.

**PHP**

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: application/json');
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/include/config.php"); 
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

**here is my code**

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                const action = $(this).attr('data-act');


                var hash = $(e.relatedTarget).data('hash');
                var para = $(e.relatedTarget).data('para');
                var ref = $(e.relatedTarget).data('ref');
                $.ajax({
                    //data :{action: "showroom"},
                    url: '/include/ajax/dashboard_get_single_card.php', //php page URL where we post this data to view from database
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {"action": action, "hash": hash, "para": para}, //Pass $id
                    dataType:'text',
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        //window.location.href = data;
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#fetched").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                        $("#fetched").html(xhr.responseText);
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        console.log(xhr.statusText);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(error);
                        //window.location.href = '/404.php';
                    }
                });


            });
            return false;
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm" id="custId" data-toggle="modal" data-act="msold" data-hash="6d8ce77d206011027297b693be999704" data-para="A4IxzuRP8ATv"><i class="mi mi-sml">local_offer</i>Mark&nbsp;as&nbsp;sold</a>
```

can some one explain why am facing this problem, because console log show `success` but no data is received in php

Comment: change `type: 'POST'` to `method: 'POST'`. Or just use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @kmoser no ajax request when changed to `method: 'POST'`

Comment: What do you mean "no ajax request"? Are you getting an error? If so, where and what is the error?

Comment: @kmoser i tried `$.post("/include/ajax/dashboard_get_single_card.php", {name: "John", time: "2pm"})
                            .done(function (data) {
                                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                            });` same request success but no data send, no `alert`

Comment: @kmoser here find the live demo https://sanojword.000webhostapp.com/dashboard/testindex

Comment: That page has Javascript errors which will prevent it from working. Check your console.